# Android Strings turn to random number after proguard Obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

I just used the new ProGuard tool in eclipse to obfuscation my application.  The I decompiled it using [dex2Jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) to inspect what happened.

I noticed that everything from the R class has been converted to a random number like the following.

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(localActivity, 2130903058, localCursor, arrayOfString, arrayOfInt);
```

2130903058 was a layout file.  Strings an arrays get the same treatment.

There is no R class in the decompiled code, where has it gone?  Where are the references to the original strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All references are integers. If you look at [`R.string`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html), you'll notice all the members are `int`s. This is because they are **pointers** to the actual strings. For example, [`android.R.string.cancel`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html#cancel) is always `17039360`, which points to the string `Cancel`. What ProGuard does is it replaces these references with the actual numbers they represent, so if you use `android.R.string.cancel`, it will replace it with `17039360`.

**Edit:** There is no R class because it is not needed anymore (all references to it have been replaced).